# Inserting "99" after every prime number in an array (with two functions)

Tags: c++, primes, function-call

I have some trouble with the parameters (this is my first attempt of using two functions) when constructing the function and calling it.

Here is the debugger's error:

```
I:\c++\11_Tombos feladatok-beszuras_torles\19.cpp||In function 'bool isPrime(int*)':|
I:\c++\11_Tombos feladatok-beszuras_torles\19.cpp|11|error: 'i' was not declared in   this scope|
I:\c++\11_Tombos feladatok-beszuras_torles\19.cpp|16|error: 'i' was not declared in   this scope|
I:\c++\11_Tombos feladatok-beszuras_torles\19.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
I:\c++\11_Tombos feladatok-beszuras_torles\19.cpp|34|error: too few arguments to  function 'bool isPrime(int*)'|
I:\c++\11_Tombos feladatok-beszuras_torles\19.cpp|9|note: declared here|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

And here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int t[])
{
    for(int j=2; j<=sqrt(t[i]); j++)
    {
        if(t[i]%j==0)
            return false;
    }

    if(t[i]<2)
        return false;

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int t[50], n, i;
    cout<<"Size of array: ";
    cin>>n;
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<". Element: ";
        cin>>t[i];
    }
    i=1;
    while(i<=n)
    {
        if(isPrime())
        {
            for(int j=n; j>=i+1; j--)
            {
                t[j+1]=t[j];
            }
            t[i+1]=99;
            n++;
            i=i+2;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cout<<t[i]<<", ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I know that system("pause") is slow and it's not recommended etc. Don't blame me for using it (suggest something else instead).

Comment: You probably want to be including <cstdlib> and <cmath> if this is c++. Doesn't fix your problem though.

Comment: So many issues with this code.  The first thing you need to do is read the error messages.  Start at the top one and fix it (`i` shouldn't even be in there, and you probably shouldn't be passing the array).  The next one tells you that you need to supply a parameter when you call `isPrime`, otherwise it doesn't know what you're testing.  If you're confused about all this, maybe take a step back and read a couple of chapters from a good book on C.

Comment: No, this is what I want to include (cmath does the same as math.h and I use cout and cin operands witch are not recognized by the compiler using cstdlib). Nothing is bad with the includes. Maybe I'm a beginner but not this much

Comment: cout and cin are in the iostream header... not sure how cstdlib would affect that

Comment: sorry for that above, i realized later that it's another header. But it still didn't resolved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a code review. :)

1. `isPrime` should take an `int t` parameter, not an array. You also use `t[i]` in this function, but `i` is out of scope! You declared `i` in `main`. Replace both `t[]` and `t[i]` with just `t`. Or, even better, call it `number` instead so it's super clear.
2. You declare `int i` on the first line of `main`, and then again in the for loop directly beneath it that initializes the `t` array. I'm surprised this didn't cause a compilation error.
3. In the for loops that start like `for(int i = 1;...`, you will miss the first element of the array every time! **Remember:** arrays are indexed from 0, so those should be `for(int i = 0;...`.
4. No error checking on user input (statement `cin >> n` in `main`). What if I enter 100? Your array `t` in `main` holds 50 integers, so `t[100]` would cause your program to crash with a segfault.
5. In the while loop of `main`, the line `if(isPrime())` won't compile because you defined `isPrime` to take a parameter, but you aren't calling it with any parameters. I think you meant `if(isPrime(i))`?
6. In the for loop right below that, you initialize `int j = n`, then try to access `t[j+1]`, which isn't allocated. This will also cause your program to crash.
7. Why do you have `n++` in the while loop? I can see this causing problems/unintended behavior because this is the bound on your while loop.
8. When writing C++ code, it's good practice to use the C++-style headers. So instead of `#include <stdlib.h>` use `#include <cstdlib>`, and instead of `#include <math.h>` use `#include <cmath>`.

There are probably a few more bugs/issues, but that should get you moving. Let us know what you come up with!

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer, that i was waiting for.

Answer (score 2):

The debugger's error tells you exactly what is wrong!

1. i does not exists in method isPrime(). Just because you have an i in the main(), you can not use it in another function (read about [Scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29))
2. You call the isPrime() function without a parameter.

I suggest you start with easier programs, and also read about [functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/).

Comment: All you wrote is my fault. I know about the scope, but thecode what i copied there was oneof my tries to resolve the prolem

Answer (score -2):

You should use something like

`cin.ignore();`

instead of `system("PAUSE");`

Comment: You should have put this as a comment on his question.